# Setting Bounded mailbox for an actor that uses stashing

Tags: java, scala, akka, messaging, actor

I have an actor that depends on stashing. Stashing requires `UnboundedDequeBasedMailbox`. Is it possible to use stashing together with `Bounded` mailbox ?

As  Arnaud pointed out, my setup is :

```
Actor with UnrestrictedStash with RequiresMessageQueue[BoundedDequeBasedMessageQueueSemantics]
```

and configuration :

```
akka {

    loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    loglevel = INFO
    daemonic = on

    actor {
            mailbox {
                bounded-deque-based {
                    mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.BoundedDequeBasedMailbox"
                    mailbox-capacity = 2000
                    mailbox-push-timeout-time = 5s
                }
                requirements {
                  "akka.dispatch.BoundedDequeBasedMessageQueueSemantics" = akka.actor.mailbox.bounded-deque-based
                }
            }
    }
}
```

And the error is :

```
[ERROR] 2013/12/06 14:03:58.268 [r-4] a.a.OneForOneStrategy - DequeBasedMailbox required, got: akka.dispatch.UnboundedMailbox$MessageQueue
An (unbounded) deque-based mailbox can be configured as follows:
  my-custom-mailbox {
    mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.UnboundedDequeBasedMailbox"
  }

akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: exception during creation
    at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:218) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:578) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:425) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:447) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:262) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:218) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386) [akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
Caused by: akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: DequeBasedMailbox required, got: akka.dispatch.UnboundedMailbox$MessageQueue
An (unbounded) deque-based mailbox can be configured as follows:
  my-custom-mailbox {
    mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.UnboundedDequeBasedMailbox"
  }

    at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:218) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.actor.UnrestrictedStash$class.$init$(Stash.scala:82) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at com.fg.mail.smtp.index.Indexer.<init>(Indexer.scala:38) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.fg.mail.smtp.Supervisor$$anonfun$preStart$1.apply(Supervisor.scala:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.fg.mail.smtp.Supervisor$$anonfun$preStart$1.apply(Supervisor.scala:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at akka.actor.CreatorFunctionConsumer.produce(Props.scala:369) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.actor.Props.newActor(Props.scala:323) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:534) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:560) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

If I do `Props.withMailbox("bounded-deque-based")` then I get

```
Caused by: akka.ConfigurationException: Mailbox Type [bounded-deque-based] not configured
```

ANSWER : thanks to Arnaud : The problem was the configuration, bounded-deque-based config block should be at the same level as akka config block. [Documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html) is totally misleading in this case...

```
akka {

    loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    loglevel = INFO
    daemonic = on

    actor {
        mailbox {
            requirements {
                    "akka.dispatch.BoundedDequeBasedMessageQueueSemantics" = akka.actor.mailbox.bounded-deque-based
                  }
        }
    }
}

bounded-deque-based {
    mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.BoundedDequeBasedMailbox"
    mailbox-capacity = 2000
    mailbox-push-timeout-time = 5s
}
```

Comment: I just got burned by the same confusion over where to put the mailbox configuration.  Agreed that documentation is weak on this point.

Comment: Can you point out what version of Akka this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the official Akka [stash doc](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/index.html#akka.actor.Stash) you can decide to use a Stash trait that does not enforce any mailbox type see [UnrestrictedStash](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/index.html#akka.actor.UnrestrictedStash).

If you use UnrestrictedStash you can configure manually the proper mailbox as long as it extends the akka.dispatch.DequeBasedMessageQueueSemantics marker trait.

You can manually configure your BoundedMailbox mailbox following the [mailboxes doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/mailboxes.html) with something like :

```
bounded-mailbox {
  mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.BoundedDequeBasedMailbox"
  mailbox-capacity = 1000
  mailbox-push-timeout-time = 10s
}

akka.actor.mailbox.requirements {
  "akka.dispatch.BoundedDequeBasedMessageQueueSemantics" = bounded-mailbox
}
```

I did not try it myself but it should work.

Edit : what version of Akka are you using? Looks like the stash trait definition changed with the version 2.2.0

Comment: Thank you Arnaud, that's it. Could you please elaborate a little more on the mailbox manual configuration ? So that it extends DequeBasedMessageQueueSemantics ? Apart from 'with UnrestrictedStash with RequiresMessageQueue[BoundedDequeBasedMessageQueue]', what would the configuration be ?

Comment: I edited the answer to add some info regarding mailboxe configuration.

Comment: I start to think, that the problem is in the application.conf

Comment: why are using deployment conf?

Comment: I changed it, I was experimenting, because I'm playing with it for more than an hour

Comment: I have it as you can see it now in the Question, and Mailboxes.mailboxTypeConfigurators contains akka.actor.default-mailbox only as I can see when debugging.... If I make a mistake in the configuration file, it fails to load, so that the conf is really used by akka.

Comment: Extract the bounded-deque-based config block out of the akka conf nested block. Put it at the same level.

Comment: That's it :-) Thank you for your patience Arnaud. I sometimes just don't see any logic in the configuration system.